# How to use custom VC++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, clr, pinvoke

I am trying to use a custom VC++ dll in my c# project. For doing so I followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx) article to create a custom. I was able to create a DLL, link and call in another  c++ project (***MyExecRefsDLL.vcxproj***).

Now, my intention was to use the same DLL in C# code. Therefore, I created another C# console project and tried to add reference (By right click -> Add Reference -> select project "*MathFuncDLL*") the dll as suggested in above link. I received an error saying - "A reference to 'MathFuncDLL' could not be added".

To overcome this issue I tried to create another project for VC++ dll i.e. ***MathFuncDLL2*** using a project template -> Visual C++ -> Class Library. This time I am able to reference the project in C#. Now at run time I get an error while calling a method from DLL - "EnteryPointNotFoundException was unhandled" "Unable to find an entry point named 'Add' in DLL 'MathFuncDLL2.dll'."

I've created a sample that can be downloaded from this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6&id=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6%21179#cid=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6&id=CB9B95B4DD4D63A6%211054).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you live with DllImport?

Comment: hi David - what do you mean by DLLImport? Actually I am trying to use that only, right? But I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be that C++ decorates function names when exporting. Therefore, `Add`, might actually be `@Add34ZZ`.

When running `dumpbin /exports MathFuncsDLL2.dll`, here is what is returned :

```
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001193 ?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z = ?Add@MyMathFuncs
@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(d
ouble,double))
          2    1 000011A5 ?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z = ?Divide@MyMat
hFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs:
:Divide(double,double))
          3    2 0000119F ?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z = ?Multiply@M
yMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFu
ncs::Multiply(double,double))
          4    3 00001199 ?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z = ?Subtract@M
yMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z (public: static double __cdecl MathFuncs::MyMathFu
ncs::Subtract(double,double))
```

So, the available solutions are :

- Declare your functions as `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` (and drop the namespaces)
- Run `dumpbin` when you compile and use `[DllImport("Math.dll", EntryPoint="?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z")]` If you do this, change you DllImport declaration to `[DllImport("MathFuncDLL2.dll", EntryPoint="<functionName>", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`. The good news is : The call works. The bad new is : it seems to return a pointer to the result.

Comment: thanks for such detailed info. I tried to use - "Declare your functions as extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) (and drop the namespaces)" but it seems to give another error i.e. PInvokeStackImbalance was detected.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem.
What I did was changing the Common Language Runtime Support of my VC++ DLL project into **Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)**.

Right click on the project -> Properties -> General -> ProjectDefaults -> Common Language Runtime Support.

Then I was able to add the reference to the C# project.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DllImport] to be able to call functions from any standard dll

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

Comment: I asked TS if he could use DllImport and he asked what is DllImport. What's wrong here?

Comment: Hi David - If you looked into sample i've uploaded I am already using it([DLLImport]) but still got some problem. Regarding the article link i've already looked into it but the examples it shows is calling a windows API which work fine for me too. For my requirement I am trying to call a custom DLL and calling it in C# code and having problem with it. hope it clears the confusion from my end